# change position of imageview with animation

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview, core-animation, position

i want to change position of imageview with animation. it just like draw playing card and it will sets to center anyone here who help me for this.

Code-:

```
 @interface PockerAppViewController : UIViewController 
{
  UIButton *btn;
  UIImageView *cards;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btn;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *cards;

-(IBAction)hidebtn:(id)sender;
-(void)setCards;
@end
```

--------------------------------.mfile-----------------------------

```
@implementation PockerAppViewController
@synthesize btn,cards;
```

/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.

```
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
 self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
 if (self)
 {
    // Custom initialization
 }
 return self;
}
```

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   cards = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"King.png"]];         
   //[cards setHidden:TRUE];    
  }

 -(IBAction)hidebtn:(id)sender
 {
   [btn setHidden:TRUE];    
   [self setCards];
 }

 -(void)setCards
 {
   [cards setFrame:cards.frame];
   [UIView beginAnimations:@"Move" context:nil];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
   [cards setCenter:CGPointMake(60,240)];
   [UIView commitAnimations];
 }

  -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  { 
 UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
 CGPoint pos = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
 NSLog(@"X: %f",pos.x);
 NSLog(@"X: %f",pos.y)  
  }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
   // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

     // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
  - (void)viewDidUnload {
  // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
   // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
   }

 - (void)dealloc {
 [super dealloc];
}
```

this is my data it help me to solve this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

> [URImageView setFrame:CurrentPositionFrame];
>
> [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateTableView" context:nil];
>
> [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
>
> [URImageView setFrame:ToTheNewPositionFrame];
>
> [UIView commitAnimations];

---

As **Till** pointed you can also use the Center property:

> [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateTableView" context:nil];
>
> [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
>
> [URImageView setCenter:CGPointMake(nPositionX ,nPositionY)];
>
> [UIView commitAnimations];

Thanks **Till**.

Comment: If all you need is movement, instead of reassigning the frame, use the center property.

Comment: @interface PockerAppViewController : UIViewController 
{
 UIButton *btn;
 UIImageView *cards;
 
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btn;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *cards;

-(IBAction)hidebtn:(id)sender;
-(void)setCards;
@end
--------------------------------.m file-----------------------------

Comment: @user652795: can you please update update your Question instead, can't really read the code clearly.

Comment: hey thank's it will really helpful to me to move single object and it will properly working. but i want to create animation on multiple image of array. just like there are 4 players and i draw an card to each memeber so at different position. can you please tell me about it.

Answer (score 0):

think this could be helpful
http://www.flashgamehole.com/Tong/play-game/en/